# How to create Datasource objects using jndi in netbeans

Tags: jndi

I have tried to create a data source object using jndi, but i got error like driver not found in the org.dhcp. i have dropped the odbc14.jar file in the both cataline.
which book should i refer and also tell me which book for jsf beginners?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the odbc14.jar.  (I'm assuming that you're using Oracle for your database.)  The "14" in that JAR name refers to the version of the JDK that you deploy to.  You'll be better off if you find the matching driver JAR for JDK 5 or 6.

Put the JAR in the /lib directory of your Tomcat deployment.  (You said Catalina, so I'll assume Tomcat.)

You need more than a JAR to create a JNDI data source.  [Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) are some docs to help you.  (I'll assume Tomcat 6.)

You can tell from all the assumptions that I had to make that your question is missing a lot of very important information.  I'd recommend that you bone up on [how to ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).